# Discord OAuth2 Freezing

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, discord, passport.js

I'm developing a website with Node.js and express. I want to have an option to sign in with Discord.

I've followed the guide on the [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-discord) as well as a [video guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r_tXkzBgmFc)

I can access the Discord OAuth page but when I click "Authorize" it will log my discord ID on the console but it will not redirect(supposed to redirect to /auth/success). If I click "cancel" it will immediately redirect to /auth/forbidden, as intended. There are no errors.

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const discordStrategy = require('./strategies/discordstrategy');
const app = express();

app.use(session({
   secret: "secret",
   cookie: {
      maxAge: 60000 * 60 * 24
   },
   saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use('/auth', require('./routes/auth'))

const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(80, () => {
    console.log("HTTP Server running on port 80");
});
```

**auth.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/success', (req, res) => {
    res.send("sucessful")
});

router.get('/forbidden', (req, res) => {
    res.send("forbidden")
});

router.get('/', passport.authenticate('discord'));
router.get('/redirect', passport.authenticate('discord', {
    failureRedirect: '/auth/forbidden'
}), function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/auth/success')
});

module.exports = router;
```

**discordstrategy.js**

```
const DiscordStrategy = require('passport-discord').Strategy;
const passport = require('passport');
 
var scopes = ['identify', 'guilds'];
 
passport.use(new DiscordStrategy({
    clientID: '[redacted]',
    clientSecret: '[redacted]',
    callbackURL: '/auth/redirect',
    scope: scopes
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    console.log(profile.id)
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

After Authing, discord and express use a cache system to store your user, so that you dont have to log in everytime. try going on incognito or a different account and logging in.